# Why is there no `T Task.Wait()` overload in .net

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I use an async method in my synchronous method.
That's what `Task.Wait()` was made for.

I think the code to wait synchronously for the result of a Task, is a little cumbersome to read and write.

```cs
string MyMethod() {
    // I'd expect to be able to write this as a one-liner:
    Task<string> resultTask = SomeAsyncApiCall();
    resultTask.Wait();
    string result = resultTask.Result;
    
    // this would be nicer to read and write instead
    //string result = SomeAsyncApiCall().Wait();

    return  SomeTransformation(result);
}
```

I bet the designers of .net had a good reason not to provide this overload. The only reason I can think of is error handling. But I think error handling should be as simple as wrapping the statement in a `try...catch` block. That is exactly what I'd do in an async method.

**This is a question about the reasons for this design-decision.** I can think of more or less elegant helpers myself ;-)

Comment: You dont need to call `.Wait`, you can just call `.Result`, that is a blocking call too.

Comment: ah. I see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: To be honest: I never would have expected a property access to block the thread. This (in my opinion) is a bad design decision.

Comment: Use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. It unwraps tasks and exceptions. That is, if you REALLY have to.

Comment: @htho It's only blocking the calling thread if the operation hasn't completed yet. It makes sense when you ask for the result of an incomplete operation to block and wait for it.

Comment: @JohanP Of course it makes sense. On the other hand blocking a thread is a massive intervention. To be honest I expected accessing result to throw an exception if the task had not finished yet.